# IIS encoding issue

Tags: iis, encoding

When using IIS as RPS (Reverse Proxy Server) with Weblogic, using the Weblogic ISAPI filter plug-ins,  there does not appear to be UTF-8 support for file attachment file names.

For example, the GET command with RPS in place showed  the unencoded file name, i.e.:
  10.166.45.33 - - [08/juin/2012:12:07:39 -0500] "GET
  /cs/U1/pscc/V_d1305081-b3c5-4e1e-989e-b8bdd497a1a3/ÇÖÐÅ.msg
  HTTP/1.1" 200 46088

That versus an encoded file name when RPS was *not* used:
  10.210.36.126 - - [15/May/2012:11:35:38 -0500] "GET
  /cs/U1/pscc/V_4ed65546-e138-4a84-b5b2-a2cf9f01d85f/%C3%87%C3%96%C3%9
  0%C3%85.msg HTTP/1.1" 200 46088

How do I circumvent this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem with the plugin used between IIS and WLS